# Jackson can't deserialize date set from Golang Api

Tags: java, go, time, date-formatting, jackson-databind

I'm working on a Golang Micro-service which uses Java based Cucumber tests for BDDs.

There is a date variable inside the schema and it is defined as:

```
startDate *time.Time
```

I set this value as:

```
t := time.Now()
startDate = &t
```

When I run the BDDs through Java program, I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2021-06-11T10:53:57.1124553+05:30": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2021-06-11T10:53:57.1124553+05:30': Unparseable date: "2021-06-11T10:53:57.1124553+05:30")
```

While in my BDD tests, I have:

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
```

I'm relatively new to Golang and facing issues while dealing with dates.

Until Now, I have tried:

```
t := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
tt, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, t)
startDate = &tt
```

I even tried with the `time.LoadLocation()`, but I am unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: usually, if my Api uses time, i will use  unix timestamp()  ```time.Now().Unix()```

Comment: Can you explain more, the tests are standardized, so I won't be able to make any change in that. And Unix() gives time in int64

Comment: you can check here https://programming.guide/go/format-parse-string-time-date-example.html how to uses different layouts compatible with Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go code you provided will not impact the way how the `Time` instance will be serialized as you are parsing it back into `Time` after serializing it to a `string`.

If you have control over how your date fields are serialized, you can apply the following format that should be aligned with what you provided to Jackson's `ObjectMapper`:

```
now := time.Now()
formattedDate := now.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z0700")
```

If you don't have control over how the date is serialized on the Go side, you could also adjust the date format on the Java side. The following example assumes that `time.RFC3339` is used by Go:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```